# link_to is not working in drop-down menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Iam trying to display a drop down list of categories from my database in ROR view page, and I want to give a link to delete the selected category in drop down list. I have written the following code, but its not working, please help me out

**My code is:**

**index.html.erb**

```
 <%= collection_select(:catvalue, :id, @catvalues, :id, :v_name, {}, class: 'drop-down')%>
 <%= link_to 'Destroy', {:catvalue => :id},method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

and my

**controller is:**

```
class CatvaluesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @catvalue = Catvalue.new
        @catvalues = Catvalue.all
        @categories = Category.all
    end

    def destroy
        @catvalue_del = Catvalue.find(params[:id])
        @catvalue_del.destroy
        redirect_to catvalues_path
    end
end
```

but its not working

Comment: You should put it in a form and then submit the form.

Comment: using form am getting many drop down menus, which controller do I need to use with the form,
'@catvalue = Catvalue.new'
or
'@catvalue = Catvalue.all'

Comment: @Mischa can you please give me the form header, my controller is already there. 
Thank You